# Error <Report xmlns='NonEmpty'> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, reporting-services, deserialization, xml-deserialization

Following the steps from Lesson [3: Load a Report Definition from the Report Server for SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ad8b31c-43b0-4481-a31b-090cbed4a438(v=sql.110)), I have the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled   
HResult=-2146233079  
Message=There is an error in XML document (2, 2)
.
.
InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=<Report xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'> was not expected.
```

When I reached the last line:

```
_report = (Report)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

To be sure, I had dumped the memory stream into a file, and compare that with the RDL I uploaded into the Report Server, to be exactly the same.

Comment: I just tested with an almost empty RDL file that I uploaded into Report Server, to have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of this site, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ad8b31c-43b0-4481-a31b-090cbed4a438(v=sql.105), Mr. Carnessssss managed to solve it this way:

```
    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();

    xRoot.ElementName = "Report";

    xRoot.Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition";

    xRoot.IsNullable = true;

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RDLSchema), xRoot);
```

This solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to replace the XSD in the [Lesson 2: Generate Classes from the RDL Schema using the xsd Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337455.aspx).

From:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd
```

To:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd
```

Not to "hack" it by manipulating its XmlRootAttribute.Namespace, which only good to mask the problem. New problem will emerge when we want to write the serialized object back to the Report Server as I faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136559/error-missing-a-mandatory-child-element).