# Error: "missing a mandatory child element"

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, reporting-services, xml-serialization

Following the steps from [Lesson 5: Publish the Report Definition to the Report Server for SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337428(v=sql.110).aspx), I have the following error:

> The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this
>   version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been
>   created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content
>   that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services
>   schemas. Details: The report definition element 'Report' is empty at
>   line 1878, position 3. It is missing a mandatory child element of type
>   'ReportSections'.

When I reached the last line:

```
_reportService.SetItemDefinition(reportPath, bytes, null);
```

This question is related to my previous question at [Error < Report xmlns='NonEmpty' > was not expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098286/error-report-xmlns-nonempty-was-not-expected).

I have skipped a step, [Lesson 4: Update the Report Definition Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337390(v=sql.110).aspx), just to be sure that I have not modified anything to the successfully deserialized object.

In this Lesson 5, I have successfully serialized back the untouched object into memory stream, but failed to to write it back into the Report Server. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing the XSD in the [Lesson 2: Generate Classes from the RDL Schema using the xsd Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337455.aspx).

From:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd
```

To:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have SQL 2012 as your SSRS server.

Comment: The fact is, I have setup SQL 2012 SSRS server and the RDL is deployed into it.